# How do a search a text file for a list of phrases contained in another text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file with many redundancies in English, one on each line, for example

```
in excess of
in order to
in order for
...
```

I would like to search another text document to see if it contains any of these phrases. If it does all it need do is print the phrase, I can do the rest manually. Can I do this easily on the command line?

Comment: Sure, what have you tried/searched/experimented ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure - try grep

```sh
grep -F -f phrases.txt doc.txt
```

phrases.txt

```
in excess of
in order to
in order for
```

doc.txt

```
use grep -f in order to match this line
this line won't be matched
```

you can use grep -o to only print the matched phrase - not the entire line:

```sh
$ grep -o -F -f phrases.txt doc.txt
in order to
```